# Errors in Structured Data

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data

We are updating Structured data manually to 100s of our articles created daily. Can we automate this process by any means? 
And also another worry is that current structured data shows many errors. Does these errors affect SEO.

Comment: Please read here about the Strucutred Data Article Markup: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article You can use the JSON LD format as it is widely accepted. You can tell your developers to provide values for each JSON variable. They will write a code so that all the values are added dynamically (it's a developer's job, you need not to worry about it). That's how you can automate this process. Please keep in mind all the guidelines and avoid spamming.

Answer (score 1):

#### Can structured data be automated?

It is common to add the structure to the page template.  All pages that use the same template would use the same template for their structured data.

Many content management systems have plugins to help implement structured data across many pages

#### Will errors in structured data hurt SEO?

Structured data has little to do with SEO.  It does not affect rankings.  Google shows rich snippets in search results for a few specific data types.  If your data has errors it won't show rich snippets but it won't hurt your rankings.

The only way structured data might hurt rankings would be if it is being abused.  In that case Google might penalize a site.  For example Google does not want sites trying to get star ratings appearing in the search results by marking up fake reviews.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we automate this process by any means?

In the guide **[Follow the structured data guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)** Google tells us:

> **Important: Google does not guarantee that your structured data will
>   show up in search results**, even if your page is marked up correctly
>   according to the Structured Data Testing Tool. Here are some common
>   reasons why:
>
> ...The structured data is not representative of the main content of
>   the page, or is potentially misleading.

and further ==> Relevance:

> Your structured data should be a true representation of the page
>   content.

Thus, it is explicitly required here that the content of the structured data represents the main content of the web page to which the data refers.

In your question you inform us that you are setting this data for your articles. Probably you are writing your articles with your hands, because if it is created automatically, then it is spam. Therefore, you need to create structured data with your hands. If you simply copy your data to all web pages, then it is at best not meaningful, because Google will ignore it. But if the violations have strong negative signals, then this may be the cause of manual actions.

Create your structured data with your hands and present the main content of the web page in them. This can have a strong positive result for organic traffic to your website. Currently, Google focuses its algorithms on the search for entities for Google Knowledge Graph. And it can be expressed and defined in structured data. Therefore, do not treat data as a seasonal fashion, because with their help you can respond to users' intentions regarding the subjects of your articles. Currently, work with data is very relevant.